# Prevent bxSlider from going to link while swiping

Tags: javascript, css, bxslider

I am trying to disable link on images inside bxSlider, while we swipe on mobile.

This, as you might imagine, is very annoying.

As far as I could see in their documentation (https://bxslider.com/options/) I couldn't find anything to do that.

I have also Googled some suggestions and tried some JS, but so far I couldn't make it happen.

I also tried setting "draggable='true'" on each slide element but, with no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable link clicks using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) in BxSlider's `onSlideBefore` and `onSlideAfter` callbacks respectively.

Example:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    // ...
    onSlideBefore: function() {
         $('.bxslider a').on('click', function() {
              return false;
         });
    },
    onSlideAfter: function() {
         $('.bxslider a').off('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help, I had only to correct a little bit your code, otherwise it was doing the exact same thing. So on the second function, I had to change it to onSlideAfter. And that's it, it's working perfectly. :D